# Javascript Tree Lables/ Levels

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var myArray = [{
    title: "Title 1",
    children: [{
      title: "Title 1.1",
      children: [{
        title: "Title 1.1.1"
      }]
    }, {
      title: "Title 1.2",
      children: []
    }]
  },
  {
    title: "Title 2",
    children: [{
      title: "Title 2.1",
      children: [{
        title: "Title 2.1.1"
      }]
    }, {
      title: "Title 2.2",
      children: [{
        title: "Title 2.2.1"
      }]
    }]
  }
];
```

So I have an array that looks similar to this.
The titles are random but what I want to get is the level eg

```
{ title: 'Title 2.2 (or any othe random title)', level: '2.2', children:[...]}
```

I would like this to be recursive and a lodash solution would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
function addLevel(array, levels) {
    levels = levels || [];
    array.forEach(function (o, i) {
        o.level = levels.concat(i + 1).join('.');
        if (Array.isArray(o.children)) {
            addLevel(o.children, levels.concat(i + 1));;
        }
    });
}

var myArray = [{ title: "Title 1", children: [{ title: "Title 1.1", children: [{ title: "Title 1.1.1" }] }, { title: "Title 1.2", children: [] }] }, { title: "Title 2", children: [{ title: "Title 2.1", children: [{ title: "Title 2.1.1" }] }, { title: "Title 2.2", children: [{ title: "Title 2.2.1" }] }] }];

addLevel(myArray);

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```